# reactjs preventDefault() is not preventing the page reload on form submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

EDIT: Events are not working at all, the onSubmit and onChange functions are not being called. I have another reactapp with similar form and onChange and onSubmit works OK there.

I have a form I dont want the page to refresh when I click on submit. I tried using `preventDefault()` but I didnt work. Even onChange is printing anything on console. This form is not on page, I am using React Router to point `to='/new'` and `component={NewPost}` (NewPost is in `./components/posts/form`)

./components/posts/form.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class NewPost extends Component {
  state = {
    title: "",
    body: "",
    status: 0,
  };

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const post = e;
    console.log(post);
  };

  onChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };
  render() {
    const { title, body, status } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="card card-body mt-4 mb-4">
        <h2>New Post</h2>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Title</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="title"
              value={title}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              className="form-control"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Content</label>
            <textarea
              type="text"
              name="body"
              rows="15"
              value={body}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              className="form-control"
            />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default NewPost;
```

App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import NavBar from "./components/layout/navbar";
import store from "./store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import Dashboard from "./components/posts/dashboard";
import NewPost from "./components/posts/form";
import {
  HashRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  Redirect,
} from "react-router-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <React.Fragment>
            <div className="container">
              <NavBar />
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard}></Route>
                <Route exact path="/new" component={NewPost}></Route>
              </Switch>
            </div>
          </React.Fragment>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

[image]

Comment: Provide All of your code, like you're routers and related components

Comment: what's the problem? it's working fine https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-shirley-d6lzd?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial events are disconnected/not working on my app. I am not even getting the output of console.log(e.target.value); on my end.

Comment: He already made a codesandbox for you without issues, if you can't reproduce the problem meaning you have a problem elsewhere which not related to the question

Comment: did you tried e.stopPropagation()?

Comment: @LucasSimões onSubmit is not getting called.

Comment: @DennisVash I realize that but my project doesn't have anything else? 2 Reducer cases for Get and Post posts, 2 action,1 component to display posts other form to send data to API. I have running the form standalone (i disabled every other component except redux) and still got the same facing the same issue, but same code on new project is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is not related to code. I created new react application and moved all my code now everything is working fine.